# R as.factor() and factor() only convert my variables into character and not factor levels

Tags: r

let's say i created such data table:

```
a = c(1,2,3,4,2,2,5,3,1)
b = c(4,5,2,2,1,1,1,1,3)
c = c(1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1)
abc = rbind(a,b,c)
abc = as.data.frame(t(abc))
str(abc)
```

and the last line will return the following data table:

```
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3 4 2 2 5 3 1
 $ b: num  4 5 2 2 1 1 1 1 3
 $ c: num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

i want to convert column a & b into factors:

```
abc[,c("a","b")] = apply(abc[, c("a","b")], 2, factor)
```

but for some reason its just not turning into factors but characters instead:

```
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ b: chr  "4" "5" "2" "2" ...
 $ c: num  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

but if i do it individually:

```
abc[,'c'] = as.factor(abc[,'c'])
```

it will work:

```
> str(abc)
'data.frame':   9 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ b: chr  "4" "5" "2" "2" ...
 $ c: Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 2
```

why is this happening? why cannot I convert these numbers into factors???
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use `lapply` instead of `apply` to avoid matrix coercion.

Comment: and it can be seen with `class(abc[, 1])` returns `"numeric"` but `class(abs[, 1:2]` returns a `data.frame`. As data.frame are (also) lists, `lapply(abc[, 1:2], factor)` will work where `apply(abs[, 1:2], 2, factor)` expects (and actually coerces to) a matrix (more generally an array)

Comment: It's not that `apply()` expects an array (this would be an issue with other inputs), but that it returns a matrix -- after the two factors are created by the first part of apply, they are coerced to character when forming the return value. You could convince yourself of this (but use `lapply()` instead!) with `unlist(apply(abc[,1:2], 2, function(x) list(factor(x))), recursive=FALSE)`.